# Non-existing property of template specification

Tags: c++, templates

Most likely it is well-discussed problem but I just do not know how to google it properly. I have a template function for two specifications: pointer to **int** and **vector** of **int**s. In this function I have a parameter **N** that is the length of the array of **int**s. If I use **vector**, I want to check if this **N** is the same as **x.size()**, so my code is something like this:

```
// foo.cpp
#include "foo.h"
template void foo<int *>(int *, int);
template void foo<std::vector<int>&>(std::vector<int>&>,int);
template <class T>
void foo(T x, int N){
    if ( std::is_same<T, std::vector<int>&>::value && N!=x.size() ) {
    // do something
    }
}

//foo.h
template <class T>
void foo(T x, int N);
```

The problem here is that there is no method **size()** for array of **int**s. I made the if-statement with AND operator in such a way that the second part won't be called if the first failed, and I had a hope the compiler could have guessed that, but it did not compile anyway.

Is there an easy solution for that? I do not want to create a new function specifically for **vector** type, as it completely eliminates all the reasons for using templates.

Comment: First, this should not compile: you are attempting to declare specializations before the primary template. I assume in your actual code they are in correct order. Second, the check in the primary template is pointless - it will never be instantiated with `T=std::vector<int>&` since you've provided a specialization for this case. What's the ultimate goal of the exercise? This looks like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: @Igor: In my actual code they are in this order but I also have a header file that I included now here. I do have T=std::vector<int>& specification. Why would not it compile?

Comment: Well, `foo.cpp` as shown doesn't actually include `foo.h`, and so still wouldn't compile.

Comment: If one is using a `std::vector`, there is no need to pass the length as a separate argument, you would just use `x.size()`. If you want to be as generic as possible, do `N = x.size()` and use `N`.

Comment: @Igor: right, corrected it.  @0x499602D2 But I won't have `x.size()` if I use `T=int*`

Comment: @Vasily Good point. Then you might want to have two overloads: One that takes a `vector`, and another that converts the `int*` array to a vector and passes it to the first overload.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [if constexpr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_If) (since C++17) to discard unwished statements.

> If the value is `true`, then *statement-false* is discarded (if present), otherwise, *statement-true* is discarded.

```
template <class T>
void foo(T x, int N){
    if constexpr ( std::is_same<T, std::vector<int>&>::value ) {

        // only for T = std::vector<int>&
        if ( N!=x.size() ) {
            // do something
        }
    }
}
```

Before C++17, you need to provide a [full specialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization) for `T = std::vector<int>&`.

Comment: Just a noobish question. Is c++1z the same as c++17 thing? I have CodeBlocks, I am not sure it has c++17.

Comment: @Vasily It was referred to as C++1z before the standard was completed.